# How to add variables in a class programmatically in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add Variable in a Class Programmatically?
for example this is my current Variables in my class

**Before**

```
  class ChartSampleData {
      ChartSampleData({
        this.yValue1,
        this.yValue2,
      });
    
      num yValue1;
      num yValue2;
    }
```

Is there any way to add variable programmatically based on how many i want
just like this:

**After**

```
class ChartSampleData {
  ChartSampleData({
    this.yValue1,
    this.yValue2,
    this.yValue3, // NEW
    this.yValue4, // NEW

  });

  num yValue1;
  num yValue2;
  num yValue3; //NEW
  num yValue4; //NEW
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You can use Map to add and get values.
For example

```
class ChartSampleData {
  ChartSampleData({

  });

  Map values = Map();
  addNewValue(String key, String value) {
    values.add(key, value);
  }

  String getValue(String key){ 
    return values[key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can use a list or array or any data structures that allow adding or removing elements. Example:

```
class ChartSampleData{
  List<num> yValues;

  ChartSampleData({this.yValues});
}
```